# How do I get zip code level data from acs for all zipcodes in the US? geo.make is not working

Tags: r, acs, zipcode

I am trying to get a table from the ACS with zip code level data, for all zip codes in the US
When I try using geo.make from the acs library I get an error term. Can anyone advice on how to get the desired table?

If I run:

```
    library(acs)
 api.key.install(key="592bc14cnotarealkey686552b17fda3c89dd389")
    zipcodes<-geo.make(zip.code="*", check=T)
```

I get the following error:

```
Testing geography item 1: Zip Code Tabulation Area * .... Error in dimnames(acs.obj@standard.error) <- list(acs.obj@geography[[1]],  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In acs.fetch(endyear = endyear, span = span, geography = geography[[1]],  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what "ACS" is? The error I get is "Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '', probable reason 'No such file or directory'"

Comment: Thanks for checking. The ACS is the american community survey, and the package and library acs downloads data with an api. To run it, you need to install the api key, for example  api.key.install(key="592bc14cnotarealkey686552b17fda3c89dd389"). Once you install this api key, then you would get the error I got. I  edited the post accordingly.